# How to utilise Opencsv annotations within intelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, maven, csv, intellij-idea, opencsv

I am trying to use Opencsv's [annotation functionality](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/index.html#annotations_2) but cannot get it working.

I added the import the as per [this link](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/library.html#add-library-to-module-dependencies) *(`import au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVReader;` is at the top of my code)* and still after selecting the *'annotations'* checkbox in the IntelliJ [import dialogue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/niXFu.png) the annotations are not found. After checking the module again the annotation checkbox remains empty.

I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Which specific jars did you add to the module dependencies?

Comment: @CrazyCoder ```au.com.bytecode:opencsv:2.4```.

Comment: Provide the list of the .jar files.

Comment: @CrazyCoder Afaik I don't have any. How can I see this?

Comment: Like this for `com.opencsv:opencsv:5.0`: https://i.imgur.com/0aSggIY.png, https://i.imgur.com/DY1nFy1.png.

Comment: @CrazyCoder You've helped me solve this since after using the one listed in your image it is now working, I must have used the wrong one.

In the future how can I know which one I should use? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure to use the correct dependency: `com.opencsv:opencsv:5.0`.

[image: com.opencsv:opencsv:5.0]
[image: com.opencsv:opencsv:5.0]